# How to get place type in Core Location/MapKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mapkit, core-location

When I use `Google Places API` to search places, I can get business or establishment type (available types are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)). But if I try to use `Apple's native Core Location or MapKit`, there's no such information available via standard classes, despite the fact that Apple Maps shows POIs with various icons, depending on `POI type`. Is it possible to get the same info from `Swift/ObjC`?